# Fill (refresh) gridview on Form2 when FocusedRowChanged on Form1

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

On `Form1` I do `FocusedRowChanged` event and I want to fill `GridView` by `ID`  on `Form2`, but my `GridView` on `Form2` not refreshing and data not loading, what I do wrong?

**Form1:**

```
private void grvAsmenys_FocusedRowChanged(object sender,
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    Form2 frmForm2 = new Form2();
    frmForm2.taKlaus.FillByID(frmForm2.dsKlaus.Klaus,
        Convert.ToInt32(Id()));
}

public object Id()
{
    var id = grvAsm.GetRowCellValue(grvAsm.FocusedRowHandle, "ID");
    return id;
}
```

Comment: What is `FillByID` method? Can you add the code into your question?

Comment: FillByID = SELECT ID,  Klaus1, Klaus2 FROM Klaus WHERE (ID = @ID)

Comment: There is not enough information. Can you copy the whole code of your method and add it into your question? Use the «edit» link below your question.

Comment: I make this method with TableAdapterQuery configuration Wizard, what exatcly i need to copy?

Comment: Ok. I think the problem is not belongs to this method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating new `Form2` class instance everytime when you a changing the focus. Instead, you need to widen the scope of your `frmForm2` variable to get the current `Form2` instance. You can promote it to field.
For example:

```
private Form2 _frmForm2; //Field for holding the current Form2 instance.

public void ShowForm2()
{
    _frmForm2 = new Form2();
    _frmForm2.Show();
}

private void grvAsmenys_FocusedRowChanged(object sender,
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    //Form2 frmForm2 = new Form2();
    //Use the field instead.
    _frmForm2.taKlaus.FillByID(_frmForm2.dsKlaus.Klaus,
        Convert.ToInt32(Id()));
}
```